# Android widget is removed when I update my application

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, app-update

When i update my application to the latest version, the widget is getting removed and the user have to add it manually, which is a wrong behavior.This is the same behavior in all the android OS version's.

Any idea!!!

Comment: Did you change the name or package of your `AppWidgetProvider` subclass?

Comment: No, i haven't changed any of them. In fact when i update my app from minor version to minor version (say 2.50.2.45 to 2.50.2.76) it works fine but when i update from major to major version (2.42.2.538 to 2.50.0.73) this issue raises.